# DOMDocument xmlns attributes - how to get them?

Tags: php, attributes, namespaces, domdocument

I'm using DOMDocument to read an XML  (SVG), which has namespaces in it.
I iterate through the attributes of all nodes, but I can't seem to get the 'xmlns' type attributes of the root element.

The XML looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"

   id="svg2"
   sodipodi:version="0.32"
   inkscape:version="0.48.1 "
   viewBox="0,0 534,616"

   ...
>
```

When I try something lke this :

```
$node= DOMDocument->documentElement;
foreach($node->attributes as $attribute) {
  echo $attribute->nodeName."\n";
}
```

I do get the 'other' attributes like id, viewBox, etc. but not the xlmns:dc, etc.

Is there a way to get those too ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572365/enumerate-registered-namespaces-of-a-php-domdocument-object

Comment: So it's not possible without using simplexml that reads the whole xml again?   I need to reproduce the XML exactly like it was read. I find it VERY strange that this wouldn't be possible with DOMDocument...

Comment: You can go from a particular prefix to its associated URI and vice-versa, but yes, ext/dom doesn't have a function or property that gets you *all* the namespaces used in a document or node.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `namespaceURI`

> The namespace URI of this node, or NULL if it is unspecified.

To get the default namespaceURI of the root node, you use

```
$dom->documentElement->namespaceURI;
```

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/o4D18q)

See my answer in the linked duplicate on how to get all the namespace attributes.

An alternative to that would be using XPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('namespace::*', $context) as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

[demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zF9J6b)

Answer (score 1):

If you are parsing through the document, extracting the namespace prefixes from each attribute value and then using `DOMNode::lookupNamespaceURI` ( string $prefix ) to build the prefix-uri mappings will result in less overhead than using simplexml.