# Xpath factory does not consider all (maybe)concurrent namespaces

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

I have a problem* about parsing an xml file with both a prefix-less namespace and a standard one with prefix ('video'): I always get null on all tags that have a "video" prefix... 
I already did the same with multiple prefixes for the same file, and that went ok.
 I only get the problem with that very one... and since it's also the first time I have a "no prefix" namespace, I am not sure the problem comes from this prefix-less namespace, or from the very video one.

Here's some sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xtx3pa_decouvrez-l-onyx-voiture-des-reves-de-peugeot_news</loc>
    <video:video>
      <video:player_loc allow_embed="yes">http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/video/xtx3pa?autoPlay=1</video:player_loc>
      <video:title>Découvrez l'Onyx, voiture des rêves de Peugeot</video:title>
      <video:description>Révélée au Mondial de l'Automobile ce matin, la dernière concept-car du constructeur a fait sensation.</video:description>
      <video:publication_date>1348768884</video:publication_date>
      <video:tag>mondial</video:tag>

      <video:category>news</video:category>
      <video:language>FR</video:language>
    </video:video>
  </url>
  <url>  ...</url>...
```

And here's is the code I use, following and example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465840/xpath-xml-namespaces-and-java) :

```
  static public class MyNamespaceContext implements NamespaceContext {
     final private Map<String, String> prefixMap;
     MyNamespaceContext(Map<String, String> prefixMap)
     {
         if (prefixMap != null)
         {
             this.prefixMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, String>(prefixMap));
         }
         else
         {
             this.prefixMap = Collections.emptyMap();
         }
     }
     public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return null;
     }
     public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return null;
     }
     public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
             if (prefix == null) throw new NullPointerException("Invalid Namespace Prefix");
             else if (prefix.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX))
                 return "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
             else if ("video".equals(prefix))
                 return "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1";
             else    
                 return "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
     }


 }

XPathFactory fabrique = XPathFactory.newInstance();
xpath = fabrique.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new MyNamespaceContext(null));
final String videosPath = "//urlset/url";
try{
    XPathExpression exp = xpath.compile(videosPath);
    videoLists = (NodeList)exp.evaluate(inDoc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
}catch(XPathExpressionException e){
    logger.info("oops",e);
    }
for(int i=0; i<videoLists.getLength(); i++){
    Node node = videoLists.item(i);
    XPathExpression exp = xpath.compile("video:video/video:title");
        String title = exp.evaluate((Element)node);
        XPathExpression exp2 = xpath.compile("loc");
        String loc = exp2.evaluate((Element)node);

        logger.info("title  : " +title); // => null
        logger.info("loc : " + loc); => http://www.dailymotion.com/swf/video/xtx3pa?autoPlay=1
}
```

(*) (no to mention, I am a perfect beginner in DOM / xpath / and so on)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your XPath expression. In XPath 1.0, no prefix always means no namespace. If you want to access nodes in a namespace (even the default namesspace), you have to use prefixed names in the XPath expression. You can't use a NamespaceContext to map the "null prefix" to a namespace, because the XPath spec doesn't allow it.

Why not move to XPath 2.0 which is more flexible? It's well supported in Java, for example by the Saxon library. XPath 1.0 has been obsolete for years.

Comment: I have shown all three... not sure I understand wich one is missing? And also, didn't realize I was using XPath 1.0... so I will have a look to Saxon. Thanks for the tips! I'll give the results on next tuesday (leaving for the WE).

Comment: Your Java code is binding a namesapce for XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX, but that has no effect because in the XPath expression, an unprefixed name always refers to a name in no namespace.