# Extract XML attribute ignoring namespace

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have to extract `attr` value from such XML:

```
<FIXML xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2">
    <TAG attr="value">
       ...  
    </TAG>
</FIXML>
```

and try to use such Java code

```
XPathExpression expression = XPathExpressionFactory.createXPathExpression("/FIXML/TAG/@attr");
XmlPayloadConverter converter = new DefaultXmlPayloadConverter();
Node node = converter.convertToNode(xmlStr);
Object result = expression.evaluateAsString(node);
```

Unfortunately, the `result` value is always empty here. If I remove namespace attr `xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-5-0-SP2"` the code works as expected (`result` has `value` string).

How to ignore the namespace in my Java code example?

**UPDATE**: looks like I have to use XPath `local-name()` function in my expression but how to use it practically in my case?

**SOLUTION**: in my case the correct XPath exprtssion is `"/*[local-name()='FIXML']/*[local-name()='TAG']/@attr"`

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939636/how-to-use-xpath-on-xml-docs-having-default-namespace

Answer (score 1):

Something similar was posted/answered here:
[How to retrieve namespaces in XML files using Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122463/how-to-retrieve-namespaces-in-xml-files-using-xpath)

> An alternative would be to forget about associating a prefix with that
>   namespace, and just make your path namespace-free. You can do this by
>   using the local-name() function whenever you need to refer to an
>   element whose namespace you don't know. For example:

```
//*[local-name() = 'Element']
```

Comment: Could you provide correct XPath expression for my case? I already tried to use `local-name()` but constantly got XPath compilation errors.

Comment: When I was dealing with trying to extract an attributes value using Transact SQL, I played around with it for hours until I found the solution.  Unfortunately I can't help you with Java.

With that said, I don't actually see any namespace on your XML. That looks like <a:element> where "a" is the namespace. Your xmlns attribute looks like its defining a namespace in an invalid way.

Comment: Namespace definition: `<f:table xmlns:f="http://www.w3schools.com/furniture">
<f:name>African</f:name>
</f:table>`

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun - Try the xpath `/*[local-name()='FIXML']/*[local-name()='TAG']/@attr`. @EdHayes3 - The xmlns is fine. The namespace uri does not have to be bound to a prefix. When it's not bound, it's usually referred to as a ["default namespace"](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting).